# Need to determine which prerequisites are missing to allow exe to run

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I've written a collection of applications (5) at home that I'm trying to use on my (and other colleagues) work computers, but I tried setting it up on a new workstation and encountered the extremely unhelpful error of "Application has encountered an error and needs to close" and I'm racking my brain to think of something else I can try to attempt to get it working.

It was not a request to install something else first, nor was it a simple unhandled exception. Just plain refusal, with an option to tell Microsoft, *pfft*.

---

**I have made sure of the following:**

All workstations are running Windows 7 SP1 x64 with DirectX 11 and admin privileges.

I tried installing the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2015 but it or newer version is already installed.

All apps have target .NET Framework 4. *I tried installing other .Net frameworks 4.5, 4.6.2 and 4.7 to no avail.*

All apps use Option Strict On (in case it matters)

All apps use Target CPU: AnyCPU

All apps have Imported Namespaces "Microsoft.VisualBasic" **UNTICKED**

Additional Namespaces I *have* imported/ticked include:

```
Microsoft.Win32
System.ComponentModel
System.IO
System.Runtime.CompilerServices
System.Runtime.InteropServices
System.Text
System.Text.RegularExpressions
System.Threading
System.Threading.Tasks
```

All apps have Enable application framework **unticked**, and startup object is Sub Main, which contains the line of code to enable visual styles and specified single-threaded apartment

All apps contain around 10 modules (many linked from common location), between 2 and 15 forms and a class or two, and a few images located under Resources.

One app has a required .dll which is alongside the .exe file, but none of them run so it can't be that.

I noticed under the Project Properties > Publish > Prerequisites there's a tick next to Windows Installer 4.5, but this pc has version 5 so not sure that's much to worry about.

---

Here's the thing, I've already got earlier versions of my software (written in XP) working on my (and others') workstations, and this copy of my new software does actually run on my work pc, but I can't set it up and test it or it will interfere with the current working versions that I'm hoping to replace.

Hence why I'm trying to test it on a new unused workstation, and I *know* it *can* work, because there's clear evidence of it. I just need help trying to find that missing link that I need to install first in order to allow it to find whatever it is that it is looking for.

Does anyone have **any clues or ideas**? Feel free to ask me anything that may be of some consequence. I'm only asking this here now because I spent well over 2 years developing this by myself and it's killing me that I can't even figure out how to make it run.

Comment: have you tried run it using visual studio on the other pc? that way, if it is a missing reference, you will know

Comment: Can you provide all the details of the error?  Look in the Windows Event Viewer and see if anything is there as well.

Comment: Go to Windows event log and check Application category. Start from errors and you should easily know what's up.

Comment: I don't have visual studio on another pc - I only own the one computer.

I will try this event viewer and see if I can work it out - never used it before but it could be handy. The error itself was very nondescript and even the error logs were encrypted so I couldn't actually read it. I'll try to attach a screenshot when I get the chance to get one and post back.
Cheers!

Comment: Turns out to be one unhandled null reference exception - which I was pretty confident I had already taken into consideration but must have missed one. I'll investigate tonight.